# How can I use Owl Carousel with Odoo 15

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, owl-carousel, odoo-15

I'am trying to use the library owl carousel 2 with odoo 15
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/index.html 
on field Many2one but i get nothing in the display
[image]

what I did is I include this files of the library in the manifest
[image]
I tried also to add them on web.assets_backend and nothing also change 
For my JS file, I add this code

```
odoo.define('slnee_appointment_core.Many2oneBackendWidget', function (require) {
'use strict';

var fieldRegistry = require('web.field_registry');
var FieldMany2One = require('web.relational_fields').FieldMany2One;
var core = require('web.core');
var qweb = core.qweb;

var Many2oneBackendWidget = FieldMany2One.extend({
    template: 'Many2oneBackendWidget',
    className: 'o_many2one_backend_widget',
    supportedFieldTypes: ['many2one'],

    init: function (parent, name, record, options) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    start: function () {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
rtl:true,
loop:true,
margin:10,
nav:true,
responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1
    },
    600:{
        items:3
    },
    1000:{
        items:5
        }
        }
    })

},


});

fieldRegistry.add('many2one_backend_widget', Many2oneBackendWidget);

return Many2oneBackendWidget;
});
```

for my xml file i add some data just for test with the class name as the library said:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
<t t-name="Many2oneBackendWidget">

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
</t>
</templates>
```

if i remove the start function from my js

```
start: function () {
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    rtl:true,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
            }
            }
        })

    },
```

the template work
[image]

but not the carousel and I tried many things to make it work and still no solution